# Getting alpha from normal and darken color

Tags: colors, less, interpolation

Given

```
darkColor = darken(normalColor, alpha)
```

`darkColor` and `normalColor` are **known**, `alpha` is unknown.

How can I calculate `alpha`?

How should I interpolate alpha if multiple color tuples (`normalColor`, `darkColor`) are presented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Less docs, the below is how [`darken()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-darken) function is defined:

> Decrease the lightness of a color in the HSL color space by an absolute amount.

So given the normal color and its darkened version, the logic to find the ***percentage*** is to find out the lightness of both the normal color, the dark color and then subtract the latter from the former. Less has a built-in function to calculate the [`lightness()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-channel-lightness) of a given color also and so it can be used directly.

```css
@normalColor: #AAAAAA;
@darkColor: #6A6A6A; /* this is darken(@normalColor, 25%) */

#dummy{
  percentage: lightness(@normalColor) - lightness(@darkColor);
}
```

**Notes:**

- Calculation is lightness of normal color - lightness of dark color as `darken` ***decreases*** lightness.
- The output is an approximate value and not accurate. For example, in the above case the output is 25.09803922% and not 25%. We cannot round down the  output value also because deviation can be positive or negative. For example, if the dark color is `#919191` (= `darken(@normalColor, 10%)`), the calculated output is 9.80392157%.
- This method works only when the dark color is ***actually a darkened version*** of the normal color. That is, the `hue` and `saturation` of the two colors should be the same as the `darken` function modifies only the `lightness`.